# Restrict an admin user from using sudo on os x

Tags: macos, permissions, sudo

I have multiple admin users on my mac. Is there a way I can block a particular admin user from executing `sudo` on OS X?

My understanding is that if the user name is "abc",

```
abc    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

in `/etc/sudoers` gives him permissions to execute `sudo`. On the similar lines, is there a way to remove permissions fro user abc?

Comment: If he is a admin user, why is he not allowed to use sudo? If you want to restrict a user to use sudo, remove him from the group `wheel` (or sometimes `sudo`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there a way I can add an Active Directory user to admin group?

Comment: To add a user to a group use: `useradd -G {group-name} username`

Comment: I dont think "useradd" is available on os x.

Comment: `sudo dscl localhost -append /Local/Default/Groups/thegroupname GroupMembership theusername`